# Garbage Value Upon Reading from Stream opened using fmemopen()

Tags: c++, c, raspberry-pi, filestream

I opened a memory stream using fmemopen() in mode 'w+'. I wrote some data tho this file and then I am trying to read the data to count no. of lines written. But I am getting garbage value by accessing this file using fgets(). My code is huge so I am just writing chunks of it here to give you an idea what I am doing.

This is how I opened the stream:

```
char        buf_sn[10000];
size_t      len = 10000;

TokenStream = fmemopen(buf_sn, len, "w+");
    if (TokenStream == NULL) {
        printf("Unable to Open Token Stream for processing\n\r");
        return FALSE;
    }
```

This is where I am writing to the stream:

```
fprintf(TokenStream,"%.*s %d %ld\n",(tok_index_l), token_s, tok_type_l,line_no_l);
        printf("\nToken::%.*s\n",(tok_index_l),token_s);
        fflush (TokenStream);
```

Now when I read data directly from the buffer I get correct output:

```
printf ("\n\n\nbuf=\n%slen=%ld\n", buf_sn, len);
```

Output:

```
. 2 1
section 1 1
. 2 1
init 1 1
. 2 2
globl 1 2
_ 2 2
start 1 2
MOVI 1 4
R0 1 4
, 2 4
0x20000000 4 4
MOVI 1 5
R1 1 5
, 2 5
0x00200000 4 5
ORR 1 6
R0 1 6
, 2 6
R0 1 6
, 2 6
R1 1 6
, 2 6
0 1 6
MOVI 1 8
R1 1 8
, 2 8
0x00040000 4 8
STRI 1 9
R1 1 9
, 2 9
R0 1 9
, 2 9
4 3 9
MOVI 1 11
R1 1 11
, 2 11
0x00010000 4 11
loop 1 13
: 2 13
STRI 1 13
R1 1 13
, 2 13
R0 1 13
, 2 13
40 3 13
MOVI 1 15
R2 1 15
, 2 15
0 1 15
wait1 1 16
: 2 16
ADDI 1 16
R2 1 16
, 2 16
R2 1 16
, 2 16
1 3 16
CMPI 1 17
R2 1 17
, 2 17
0x00400000 4 17
BNE 1 18
wait1 1 18
STRI 1 20
R1 1 20
, 2 20
R0 1 20
, 2 20
28 3 20
MOVI 1 22
R2 1 22
, 2 22
0 1 22
wait2 1 23
: 2 23
add 1 23
r2 1 23
, 2 23
r2 1 23
, 2 23
# 2 23
1 3 23
CMPI 1 24
R2 1 24
, 2 24
0x00400000 4 24
BNE 1 25
wait2 1 25
BAL 1 27
loop 1 27
```

But when I access this same stream using fgets() I get garbage at the end:

```
rewind(TokenStream);        //Reset the TokenStream Pointer to the Start of the Stream.
    while(fgets(line_read_sn,sizeof(line_read_sn), TokenStream) != NULL) {
        printf("%ld>> %s\n",total_no_of_tokens_l, line_read_sn);
        total_no_of_tokens_l++;
    }
```

Output:

```
0>> . 2 1
1>> section 1 1
2>> . 2 1
3>> init 1 14>> . 2 2
5>> globl 1 2
6>> _ 2 2
7>> start 1 2
8>> MOVI 1 4
9>> R0 1 4
10>> , 2 4
11>> 0x20000000 4 4
12>> MOVI 1 5
13>> R1 1 5
14>> , 2 5
15>> 0x00200000 4 5
16>> ORR 1 6
17>> R0 1 6
18>> , 2 6
19>> R0 1 6
20>> , 2 6
21>> R1 1 6
22>> , 2 6
23>> 0 1 6
24>> MOVI 1 8
25>> R1 1 8
26>> , 2 8
27>> 0x00040000 4 8
28>> STRI 1 9
29>> R1 1 9
30>> , 2 9
31>> R0 1 9
32>> , 2 9
33>> 4 3 9
34>> MOVI 1 11
35>> R1 1 11
36>> , 2 11
37>> 0x00010000 4 11
38>> loop 1 13
39>> : 2 13
40>> STRI 1 13
41>> R1 1 13
42>> , 2 13
43>> R0 1 13
44>> , 2 13
45>> 40 3 13
46>> MOVI 1 15
47>> R2 1 15
48>> , 2 15
49>> 0 1 15
50>> wait1 1 16
51>> : 2 16
52>> ADDI 1 16
53>> R2 1 16
54>> , 2 16
55>> R2 1 16
56>> , 2 16
57>> 1 3 16
58>> CMPI 1 17
59>> R2 1 17
60>> , 2 17
61>> 0x00400000 4 17
62>> BNE 1 18
63>> wait1 1 18
64>> STRI 1 20
65>> R1 1 20
66>> , 2 20
67>> R0 1 20
68>> , 2 20
69>> 28 3 20
70>> MOVI 1 22
71>> R2 1 22
72>> , 2 22
73>> 0 1 22
74>> wait2 1 23
75>> : 2 23
76>> add 1 23
77>> r2 1 23
78>> , 2 23
79>> r2 1 23
80>> , 2 23
81>> # 2 23
82>> 1 3 23
83>> CMPI 1 24
84>> R2 1 24
85>> , 2 24
86>> 0x00400000 4 24
87>> BNE 1 25
88>> wait2 1 25
89>> BAL 1 27
90>> loop 1 27
91>> 
92>> 
93>> 
94>> 
95>> 
96>> 
97>> 
98>> 
99>> 
100>> 
101>> 
102>> 
103>> 
104>> 
105>> 
106>> 
107>> 
108>> 
109>> 
110>> 
111>> 
112>> 
113>> 
114>> 
115>> 
116>> 
117>> XA
118>> 
119>> 
120>> 
121>> `=
122>> 
123>> 
124>> *
125>> =
126>> t=
127>> 
128>> 
129>> 
130>>
```

Please help me out what is being done wrong? As in between I am not doing anything with the stream so why am I getting this output? More importantly what can I do to fix it? Thanks

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Well the fflush() is for adding '\0' at the end of the stream. while loop is actually looking for it when it say != NULL. Unless my understanding is wrong.

Comment: Hi, I am not entirely sure I understand what you are asking. Can you elaborate a bit please? Thanks

Comment: `fflush()` doesn't add anything in the end, it will just flush the buffers. `fgets()` will return NULL if there's nothing to be read. Clearly there is something there to be read for some reason

Comment: Yes: Please refer to this: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fmemopen.3.html

 "When a stream that has been opened for writing is flushed (fflush(3))
       or closed (fclose(3)), a null byte is written at the end of the
       buffer if there is space.  The caller should ensure that an extra
       byte is available in the buffer (and that size counts that byte) to
       allow for this."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a stream in memory with `fmemopen()` you give it a buffer of 10000 bytes. When you write to it `fflush()` does not insert anything, it will only inform the underlying system that buffers should be written to storage, which in this case is memory.

Then when you rewind and start reading `fgets()` will return non-NULL values as long as it can read something. Since your buffer is 10000 bytes and you're not writing that much, there is random noise to be read after your data.

You will have to write some kind of an end value to show that the actual data is over. If every line has something written on it, then the end marked can be as simple as a nul character, which makes `fgets()` to read an empty line and you can simply check that.

Comment: I already tried modifying the code to add '\0' manually but the problem persisted. I modified this: fprintf(TokenStream,"%.*s %d %ld\n",(tok_index_l), token_s, tok_type_l,line_no_l);  to this ------> fprintf(TokenStream,"%.*s %d %ld\n\0",(tok_index_l), token_s, tok_type_l,line_no_l);

Comment: @Xtreme_Enigma Is that run only once or several times? Since I think that only writes one line and you have several lines, so the additional nul should be after everything has been written, not on the same line with them. Also you can't `fprintf` a nul this way, since it will be treated as an ending character for the string literal. Try adding `fputc('\0')` after all has been written.